# Anyone working on improvements to the todo example?

Tags: meteor

The todo example's video ends with the speaker mentioning (a) adding buttons to delete an entire list (b) adding controls to let the user change the order of the items in the list.

Has anyone made these improvements?  If so, would you mind sharing?  I'd love to jump-start my way into meteor by comparing the changeset.

Comment: so, based on no feedback on this, I've undertaken to just dive in and hack.

Comment: I've created the delete list function.  Here is a "patch" (`diff -ru todos-orig todos`).

[Todos Enhancement Gist](https://gist.github.com/aks/fd8b1fad8b583be24af1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created the "delete list" function in the Meteor.com "Todos" example.

Caveat: there is no warning or alert when the user clicks on the "Delete List" icon.  There probably should be.  I'll do this next. :-)

The "Delete list" function causes all associated Todos to be deleted.  An alternative implementation might optionally retain these disassociated Todos into an "unnamed list".  Exercise left to the reader.

Enjoy

Alan S.

Below is a gist of the the patches, followed by the individual patches for the three affected files: todos.js, todos.css, todos.html.

https://gist.github.com/aks/fd8b1fad8b583be24af1

### todos.js

```
--- todos-orig/client/todos.js  2013-04-19 23:05:05.422782896 -0700
+++ todos/client/todos.js       2013-04-19 23:00:57.571651600 -0700
@@ -93,6 +93,23 @@
     // prevent clicks on <a> from refreshing the page.
     evt.preventDefault();
   },
+  'click .destroy': function (evt) { // delete list
+    var list_id = this._id;
+    // remove todos attached to this list
+    Todos.find({list_id: list_id}).
+         forEach(function (todo) { 
+           Todos.remove(todo._id);
+         });
+    // remove the list
+    Lists.remove(list_id);
+    Session.set("list_id", null);
+    var list = Lists.findOne({}, {sort: {name: 1}});
+    if (list) {
+      Router.setList(list._id);
+      Session.set("list_id", list._id);
+    }
+    Deps.flush();
+  },
   'dblclick .list': function (evt, tmpl) { // start editing list name
     Session.set('editing_listname', this._id);
     Deps.flush(); // force DOM redraw, so we can focus the edit field
```

### todos.css

```
--- todos-orig/client/todos.css 2013-04-19 23:05:05.422782896 -0700
+++ todos/client/todos.css      2013-04-19 23:31:40.682096634 -0700
@@ -121,6 +121,11 @@

 #lists .list {
     padding: 3px 6px;
+    display: block;
+    height: 30px;
+    position: relative;
+    overflow: hidden;
+    /*border-top: 1px solid #ccc;*/
 }

 #lists .selected {
@@ -129,10 +134,22 @@
     font-weight: bold;
 }

-#lists .list-name {
+#lists .list .destroy {
     cursor: pointer;
+    position: absolute;
+    left: 5px;
+    top: 5px;
+    height: 20px;
+    width: 20px;
+}
+
+#lists .list-name {
     color: black;
+    cursor: pointer;
+    float: left;
+    margin-left: 30px;
     text-decoration: none;
+    width: auto;
 }

 #createList {
@@ -201,11 +218,13 @@
     color: #999;
 }

-#item-list .todo:hover .destroy {
+#item-list .todo:hover .destroy, 
+#lists .list:hover .destroy {
     background: url('/destroy.png') no-repeat 0 0;
 }

-#item-list .todo .destroy:hover {
+#item-list .todo .destroy:hover,
+#lists .list .destroy:hover {
     background-position: 0 -20px;
 }
```

### todos.html

```
--- todos-orig/client/todos.html        2013-04-19 23:05:05.418783039 -0700
+++ todos/client/todos.html     2013-04-19 21:10:28.576711844 -0700
@@ -29,6 +29,7 @@
               <input class="list-name-input" id="list-name-input" type="text" value="{{name}}" />
             </div>
           {{else}}
+           <div class="destroy"></div>
             <div class="display">
               <a class="list-name {{name_class}}" href="/{{_id}}">
                 {{name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I've gotten a copy of Todo working, and since it was not at all trivial, for a first-timer using meteor, to do so, I'll document the major hurdle I hit, and how to get over it.

First, I used "meteor create --example todo" to pull down the todo example.

Then, (first root cause of my hurdles - overthinking) instead of just hacking on that, I started a new project using "meteor create projectname"

I then copied the 3 directories worth of files over into the new project - "client", "public", and "server".

I immediately started hacking on the files (second root cause of my hurdles - not taking baby steps) and when I tested, it ALMOST worked.

The initial render worked, the mongo db stuff was golden, double-click let me edit things... but "select" wasn't working.  I.e. the on-mousedown handler for selecting a list item wouldn't select it.

I added some alert() calls and finally learned that "Router" was null!  I decided to focus outside of the changes I had made, and see if it wasn't something more fundamental.

I checked the javascript console for errors, and sure enough, there was a big one: Backbone was undefined.

Checking the example "todo" project, "meteor list --using" told me:
underscore
backbone

...whereas in my NEW project, that same command told me I wasn't using any available packages.

When I added underscore and backbone, my copy of todo started to work properly.

Comment: 1/ What about the smart URLs thing?
2/ Where's the code ?!? :)

Comment: julien_c - unsure what you're asking about smart URLs.  Here's the code so far: https://github.com/PaulReiber/story

Answer (score 1):

I've added two new features [in my github repo](https://github.com/foobarbecue/meteor-todos) that sort of turn it into a time tracker:

- Recording and display of timestamp of completion for each todo item.
- Time tracking -- you click "active" when you're working on something and then it counts up and displays the time you spent on that item.